# Controlling multiple JPanels visibility in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

So what I want to do is create multiple jpanels of the different menus that i need. At first, only the visibility of the main menu is set to true. Then depending on which buttons I click, i can go to different menus by turning off the visibility of the previous menu and turning on the visibility of the current one. It's not working though, and I think it's with the way I add my JPanels. Any quick fix to this?

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;


public class justawindow extends JFrame{

    public  static void main (String[] args){
        justawindow w = new justawindow();
    }

    //JPanels
    JPanel mainMenu = new JPanel();
    JPanel createUserMenu = new JPanel();
    JPanel loginUserMenu = new JPanel();


    //mainMenu stuff
    JButton createMenu = new JButton("Create new user");
    JButton loginMenu = new JButton("Login");

    //createUserMenu stuff
    JTextField username = new JTextField(15);
    JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField(15);
    JTextField realname = new JTextField(15);
    JButton backFromCreateUser = new JButton("Back");
    JButton createUser = new JButton("Create new user");
    JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel("Username:");
    JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password:");
    JLabel realnameLabel = new JLabel("Real name:");
    JButton login = new JButton("Login");
    JButton backFromLoginUser = new JButton ("Back");

    public justawindow(){


        createMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                mainMenu.setVisible(false);
                createUserMenu.setVisible(true);
            }
        }); 

        loginMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                mainMenu.setVisible(false);
                loginUserMenu.setVisible(true);
            }
        });


        GridBagLayout g1 = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints c1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        mainMenu.setLayout(g1);

        c1.gridx = 0;
        c1.gridy = 0;
        mainMenu.add(createMenu,c1);
        c1.gridy = 1;
        mainMenu.add(loginMenu,c1);
        mainMenu.setVisible(true);

        GridBagLayout g2 = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints c2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        createUserMenu.setLayout(g2);

        c2.gridx = 0;
        c2.gridy = 0;
        createUserMenu.add(usernameLabel,c2);
        c2.gridx = 1;
        createUserMenu.add(username,c2);
        c2.gridx = 0;
        c2.gridy = 1;
        createUserMenu.add(passwordLabel,c2);
        c2.gridx = 1;
        createUserMenu.add(password,c2);
        c2.gridx = 0;
        c2.gridy = 2;
        createUserMenu.add(realnameLabel,c2);
        c2.gridx = 1;
        createUserMenu.add(realname,c2);
        c2.gridx = 0;
        c2.gridy = 3;
        createUserMenu.add(createUser,c2);
        c2.gridy = 4;
        createUserMenu.add(backFromCreateUser,c2);
        createUserMenu.setVisible(false);

        GridBagLayout g3 = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints c3 = new GridBagConstraints();
        loginUserMenu.setLayout(g3);

        c3.gridx = 0;
        c3.gridy = 0;
        loginUserMenu.add(usernameLabel,c3);
        c3.gridx = 1;
        loginUserMenu.add(username,c3);
        c3.gridx = 0;
        c3.gridy = 1;
        loginUserMenu.add(passwordLabel,c3);
        c3.gridx = 1;
        loginUserMenu.add(password,c3);
        c3.gridx = 0;
        c3.gridy = 2;
        loginUserMenu.add(login,c3);
        c3.gridy = 3;
        loginUserMenu.add(backFromLoginUser,c3);
        loginUserMenu.setVisible(false);


        this.add(createUserMenu);
        this.add(loginUserMenu);
        this.add(mainMenu);

        setSize(400,500);
        setTitle("Bomberman");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) maybe

Comment: But I want to switch jpanels at the click of a button. How do I do that?

Comment: You look up the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html#show(java.awt.Container,%20java.lang.String)) and relevant tutorials, like maybe using `CardLayout#show`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code may help you

```
JPanel mainMenu = new JPanel();
createUserMenu.setVisible(false);

JPanel createUserMenu = new JPanel();
createUserMenu.setVisible(false);

JPanel loginUserMenu = new JPanel();
loginUserMenu.setVisible(false);
```

ActionPerformed

```
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getSource()==btn1)
            {
                 mainMenu.setVisible(true);
                 createUserMenu.setVisible(false);
                 loginUserMenu.setVisible(false);

            }
            else  if(e.getSource()==btn2)
            {
                 mainMenu.setVisible(false);
                 createUserMenu.setVisible(true);
                 loginUserMenu.setVisible(false);

            }
            else  if(e.getSource()==btn3)
            {
                 mainMenu.setVisible(false);
                 createUserMenu.setVisible(false);
                 loginUserMenu.setVisible(true);

            } 


        }
```

This is not a complete solution, Just an Example

Comment: I know you said this is not a complete solution, but this is really messy. A better solution would be to add an anonymous `ActionListener` to each button that simply executes the logic without having to check the identity of the event source object.

Answer (score 0):

Using arrayLists

```
components1 = new ArrayList<Component>();
    components1.add(label11);
    components1.add(label12);
```

to set visibility

```
panel1.setVisible(true);
            for (Component component1 : components1) {
                component1.setVisible(true);
            }
            panel2.setVisible(false);
            for (Component component2 : components2) {
                component2.setVisible(false);
            }
            panel3.setVisible(false);
            for (Component component : components3) {
                component.setVisible(false);
            }
```